# update a row using selected id in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my view, i printed all the record in my table. and i made a button for update a row by passing its id to model. when i printed the variable that i used to get the `id`, it printed. but when i put it in a query, the query result was empty. could someone please help me, what's wrong with my code?

**here is my view code**

```
echo " <tr><td width='250' name='tanya'>$row->pertanyaan</td>
               <td name='jawab'>$row->jawaban</td>
               <td width='90'><a href='c_faq/edit?id=".$row->id_faq."' class='btn btn-default' role='button'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></a>
               <button><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'> </span></button></a>
               </td>
               </tr>";
```

**this is my controller**

```
public function edit()
{
    $data["edits"] = $this->m_faq->acts();
    $this->load->view('v_editfaq', $data);
}
```

**and this is my models**

```
public function acts()
{
    $idtemp = $this->input->get('id');
    $query= $this->db->query('select * from faq where id_faq = "$idtemp"');
    return $query->result();
}
```

when i printed the `$idtemp` , it got the right `id`. but after i put it in `$query`, the result was empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the $idtemp in '' cant berecognize to real id, it's still $idtemp,you need to put it in ""

```js
$query= $this->db->query("select * from faq where id_faq = '$idtemp'");
```

Answer (score 1):

`row_array` returns a single result and `result_array` returns multiple results which is usually used for loop cases.

Change the `query->result` to `query->row` in query-

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('faq');
$this->db->where('id_faq',$idtemp);
$result=$this->db->get()->row(); //change result to row
 return $result;
```

Also replace your double quotes in `$data["edits"]` to `$data['edits']` in your controller.

[documentation on- row_array & result_array](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: and how can i return the $result to the controller? can i just write return $result?

Comment: `$data["edits"] = $this->m_faq->acts();` Your `$data["edits"]` holds the result when we `return`.

Comment: if i want to print my $data["edits"] in my view, what should i write in my view? because usually i print an array data in my view and i've never printed only one result for the query :(

Comment: You can use `echo $edits->field_name;` on your view page. If this post was useful upvote/accept.

Comment: i want to print $edits->pertanyaan in my v_editfaq.php is that possible? it gives me an error like this while im trying to print it. "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: check whether your field name mentioned are correct,also just use `echo "<pre/>";print_r($result);exit();` in model to see your result values.